# How to delete not equal records in two different tables from the table

Tags: sql

I have A, B, C  are three different tables, I need to delete the records from A table which is not exits in both B and C tables.

Sample:

```
 delete from A 
 where name NOT IN ( select name from B inner join C);
```

Comment: Step 1. Write a `SELECT` to figure out the result set you want deleted. Step 2. Change your `SELECT` to a `DELETE`.

Comment: Do you mean `delete from a where name not in (select name from b union select name from c)` ?

Comment: @Joe can u give some other way

Comment: @nag what's the problem with Joe's approach?

Comment: @Mureinik I am not getting not equal records from A table

Answer (score 0):

I Like to use left joins for stuff like this.  I start by creating a select statement like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.Name = b.Name
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC AS c ON a.Name = c.Name
WHERE  b.Name IS NULL
       AND c.NAME IS NULL
```

Then I convert to a DELETE statement like this:

```
DELETE  a 
FROM    TableA AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.Name = b.Name
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC AS c ON a.Name = c.Name
WHERE  b.Name IS NULL
       AND c.NAME IS NULL
```